# How can I call Redux Action function from app store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I call **Redux** action function from store but error show on **store.dispatch** 
"**TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__store__.a.dispatch is not a function**".

App Store code:

```
import store from './store';
    if (localStorage.getItem("persist:root")) {
      const persistData = localStorage.getItem("persist:root")
      const root = JSON.parse(persistData)
      const field = JSON.parse(root.auth)
      const expiresIn = field['authToken']["expiresIn"]

       //check expire date
      const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
      if(expiresIn<currentTime){
        store.dispatch(logoutUser());
        window.location.href='/login';
      }
    }
```

Redux Action:

```
export const logoutUser = ()=>dispatch=>{
   //......
   dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
}
```

Create Store:

```
const initialState = {};
const middleware = [reduxThunk];
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['auth'],
  blacklist: ['errors', 'profile', 'target']
};
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
export default () => {
let store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  )
);
let persistor = persistStore(store);
return   { store, persistor };
};
```

Index.js:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
const { persistor, store } = configureStore();
ReactDom.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Comment: Can you share the code for creating the store.

Comment: Alright, Can you show how you have imported and created store in AppStore from this store file ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply I add create store code.

Comment: In App Store how are you importing `store`?

Comment: I edit the code so you can see how I import the store :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apart from store.js file, create a separate file, call it newStore.js

newStore.js

```
import configureStore from './store';

const { persistor, store } = configureStore();

export { persistor, store }
```

Modify your index file

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
--------------------------------
import { persistor, store } from './newStore'; //This is changed
--------------------------------
ReactDom.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Modify your App Store code to

```
import { store } from './newStore'; //This is changed

---------------------------
if (localStorage.getItem("persist:root")) {
  const persistData = localStorage.getItem("persist:root")
  const root = JSON.parse(persistData)
  const field = JSON.parse(root.auth)
  const expiresIn = field['authToken']["expiresIn"]

   //check expire date
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if(expiresIn<currentTime){
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    window.location.href='/login';
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.